# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'X'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I got problem with my python project, Let's say I have structure like:

```
app/
    services/
        service.py
        __init__.py
    repo/
       repository.py
       __init__.py
    tests/
        service-tests/
            test_service.py
        repo-test/
            test_repo.py
```

I need to import in test_service.py stuff from service.py.

I've been trying like:

`from ..services.service import Service`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from services.service import Service
```

and some other configuration I found in topics here but all tries resulted in:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'

or

> ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Does anyone know a solution for that? I'm working on macOS and VSCode. Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Python import src modules when running tests](/q/4761041/4518341) (Note that the answers include various solutions plus various advice.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run `test_service.py` directly in a python shell? Then you are running a top-level file with name `__main__` and python cannot find a higher level in the package. You might want to read the detail explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/5242412).

Say you have this (simplified) directory structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── service.py
│   └── tests
│       └── servicetests
│           └── test_service.py
└── testfile.py
```

Just use

```
from app.services.service import Service
```

in the module `test_service.py`. You can call functions (say, `test`) from `testfile.py` as

```
from app.tests.servicetests.test_service import test
```